# Is inconsistent language in a call-to-action button OK?

Tags: buttons, conversion

We are in the process of designing new marketing pages for our website. All of these will be designed to get a visitor to understand features and benefits and encourage them to register.

Our main registration button in some cases appears more than once on a page. In these cases, each button is labeled differently. For example, on the nav bar it's labeled "Join Now" and in the homepage body it's labeled "Get Started."

Is this problematic?

[image: HUGO Homepage]

Answer (score 1):

#### Redundancy in web design

I don't think it's something problematic and it's a widely used resource, especially by companies that encourage potential users to sign up. There are examples with up to three buttons with different labels that lead to the same place and thousands of web pages with menus and icons repeating the same content and leading to the same place.

In [Uxcel](https://app.uxcel.com/explore): <kbd>Get started</kbd>, <kbd>Get started for free</kbd> and <kbd>Start for free</kbd> lead to the register page:

[image]

The same happen in [futurelearn.com](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses) with <kbd>Sign in</kbd>, <kbd>Get started</kbd> and <kbd>Sign up now</kbd>

[Redundancy on web pages](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/141513/115107) has a double objective: to provide the page with information and offer interpretation alternatives to the user. In the question image <kbd>Join now</kbd> appears to be an option to someone who already knows the site while <kbd>Get started</kbd> is an invitation.

On a personal level, it's not a pattern that I would choose without logic. For example, going back to the image of the question, in addition to the "official button" <kbd>Join now</kbd>, I would try to graphically link it in some way to the message proposal, thus implying that it is THIS what I am inviting the user to in this section, even if it's a generic registration to the site.

[image]

There is a lot of information on the internet about **redundancy in web design**.